# Where can I find a good syntax checker for ruby to use in Emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp, syntax-error

Looking for something that works in ruby-mode like pyflakes + flymake in emacs py-mode or [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) for vim.

Answer (score 3):

[FlymakeRuby](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeRuby) does this, although I'd add the `-w` flag.

Comment: +1, I also use FlymakeRuby and am quite happy with it, especially combined with the folling elisp function that I picked up in gnu.emacs.help: `(defun my-flymake-show-help ()
   (when (get-char-property (point) 'flymake-overlay)
     (let ((help (get-char-property (point) 'help-echo)))
       (if help (message "%s" help)))))`

Comment: Yes indeed. There's a package of my version of `flymake-ruby.el` on marmalade-repo.org, for convenient installation via package.el.